# How to fill and return object in rxjava?

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

How can I rewrite this piece of code (I don't really like `.toSingle()`)?

Basically I want to:

- create a fresh object
- fill it using `rx` methods
- when fill returns `Completable.complete()`, I want to return that filled object then (as a `Single<Stats>`).

  ```
  return Single.just(new Stats(player))
               .flatMap(stats -> fillPlayerStatsCompletable(stats, gamesObservable).toSingle(() -> stats));
  ```

Comment: Can you provide more context? The answer depends a lot on how you want to "fill" it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return filled object, you need to change `fillPlayerStatsCompletable` return type to `Single<Stats>`

```
return Single
    .just(new Stats(player))
    .flatMapCompletable(stats -> fillPlayerStats(stats, gamesObservable));
```

Or, if you want to get `Completable` in the end you need to change `flatMap` to `flatMapCompletable`:

```
return Single
    .just(new Stats(player))
    .flatMapCompletable(stats -> fillPlayerStatsCompletable(stats, gamesObservable));
```